# Multiple outputs nested for each

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having a hard time filtering out the excess "option" outputs here. I'm thinking I'm confusing myself.

```
foreach ($bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base as $bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa) {
    foreach ($bv_wg_lf_rf_array as $base) {
        if ($bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa == $base){
            $bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa = strtoupper($bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa);
            $me .= '<option value="'.$bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa.'" selected>'
                   .$bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa.'</option>';
        }   
        else {
            $base = strtoupper($bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa);
            $me .= '<option value="'.$bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa.'">'
                   .$bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa.'</option>';
        }

    }
}
echo $me;
```

This on dump returns (without excess)

```
WG
WG
WG
LF
LF
LF
RF
RF
RF
```

> bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base =

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'WG' (length=2)
  1 => string 'LF' (length=2)
  2 => string 'RF' (length=2)
```

> bv_wg_lf_rf_array

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'RF' (length=2)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
```

The first array is a manually created array to determine the actual inputs while the second array is from the database. Three different columns for WG LF and RF is present(else null in db).

So basically it's spitting it out all three times rather than creating the selected option then erasing skipping and moving to the others that should be without selected.

Comment: Doesn't help that we don't have the original array. I know some people will hate on a traditional fore loop with a numeric index, but I think it might possibly might help you get less confused here.

Comment: I mean all these variable names `$bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base` and `$bv_wg_lf_rf_arrayaaa` and `$bv_wg_lf_rf_array` as `$base` when you could just have like `$bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base` and `$bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base[$i]` ... you better have lots of aspirin handy.

Comment: This is the original array @developerwjk . I do agree with you though on the var names. I'll rethink that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can reduce the array that comes from the database to a single value like this:

```
$selected = array_filter($bv_wg_lf_rf_array)[0];
```

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without a callback will remove all of the empty string values from your array.

If you have an older PHP version, it may need to be done in two statements:

```
$selected_array = array_filter($bv_wg_lf_rf_array);
$selected = $selected_array[0];
```

It looks like this could be avoided if you changed the query that produces this array to only get the selected value from the database, but I am just working with what you have here.

This will significantly simplify building your option string.

```
foreach ($bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base as $value) {
    // see if the value matches the selection
    $selected = ($value == $selected) ? 'selected' : '';
    // append the option with the appropriate 'selected' setting
    $me .= "<option value=\"$value\" $selected>$value</option>";
}
```

If you need to handle multiple selections, you can just skip the `array_filter` and use `in_array` to check your selections like this:

```
foreach ($bv_wg_lf_rf_array_base as $value) {
    $selected = (in_array($value, $bv_wg_lf_rf_array)) ? 'selected' : '';
    $me .= "<option value=\"$value\" $selected>$value</option>";
}
```

Comment: You know this is great, but I'm wondering if an issue could occur if two have been selected. So possible WG and RF for example. If we're just grabbing the first value than we'd be leaving out the next one, right? Or am I not reading that correctly?

Comment: Ah, I had assumed only one would be selected. Are multiple selections possible here?

Comment: I updated the answer to add a way to handle multiple selections.